# Selenium ChromeDriver stuck on instance creation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium for website automation.
In headless mode, everything works perfectly, but I need to see what's going on there.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var path = @"C:\qq\ChromeDriver";
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        //options.AddArgument("--headless"); //with headless no issues

        options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.AddArgument("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
        options.AddArgument("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model           
        options.AddArgument("--incognito");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(path, options); //execution stucks here
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
    }
```

My Chrome version is

```
Google Chrome   87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (32-bit) (cohort: Stable)
```

Downloaded ChromeDriver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (chromedriver_win32.zip)
```

Selenium

```
Version 3.141.0
```

Starting the program I get this:

[image]

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 57644
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

and

[image]

For a minute nothing happens and in the end, I get

[image]

Any suggestions on what should I change to make ChromeDriver work?

**Update stack trace:**

```
Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:53801/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory)
   at WebDriverAlpha.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\______\Program.cs:line 26
```

[image]

Also, I added more log and have this:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55720/devtools/browser/d265469d-9647-4e16-8f77-d2493cc1bf42
[50124:50128:1228/030625.394:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.393] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.400:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.395] USB: usb_service_win.cc:352 Could not get child device's service name: Element not found. (0x490)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.401:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.400] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.401:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.400] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.401:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.400] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.402:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.401] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[50124:50128:1228/030625.446:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.446] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1204 Getting Radio failed. Chrome will be unable to change the power state by itself.
[50124:50128:1228/030625.459:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.459] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1282 OnPoweredRadioAdded(), Number of Powered Radios: 1
[50124:50128:1228/030625.459:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [03:06:25.459] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1297 OnPoweredRadiosEnumerated(), Number of Powered Radios: 1
```

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? What user are you running your command line app as? Does that user have permission to open the browser?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include text in screenshots as plain text in your post. Images are to difficult to read.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, it's a console application. There are no admin rights, but the user has permission to open the browser and the browser is opening just stuck on the blank "data;" page

Comment: Try commenting out all of the `AddArgument` lines. Does it work? Add those lines back one-by-one and try it. Maybe one or a combination of options are causing problems.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, absolutely the same outcome. It just opens a new empty tab "data;" and crashes in 60 seconds with a timeout.

Comment: Is there already a ChromeDriver instance running on the same port number? Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I close all the processes from the task manager before the execution. Question updated with a stack trace I get.

Comment: Which line is line 26?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(path); //execution stucks here

Comment: The console output is talking about Bluetooth, and being unable to change the power state. Are you automating a mobile device? If so, which one?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I'm automating just a website, not any device. All that I'm trying to do right now is to open a google page with Selenium nothing else. From what I googled before, those warnings could be omitted as they are created only for device automation.

Comment: Is there anything else on your machine running on the same port that ChromeDriver is starting on?

Comment: Maybe anti-virus is causing issues? Try disabling anti-virus or firewalls.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, just checked all ports, no matches, it uses a free one. Probably it's something with the firewall then. I cannot disable it because I don't have local admin rights on the work computer. Do you know any way to run it in a kind of portable mod independently on the system rights?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, thank you for the attempt to help, but I gave up on it. It looks like the issue is too specific for my work system. I'm creating a chrome extension with pure js instead of the proper solution with selenium.